# go back from imageview to main screen android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-imageview

I have a method that shows a random image in an imageView and have a problem.
The random image displays fine however when i press back on the phone to go back to the main screen the app closes! and if i slide left or right on the image the odd thing is it shows other images from the array! what i want is when the user has finished looking at the image i would like to exit the imageView and see the main screen to be displayed again! thank you

```js
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView thumbPrint;
    private TextView result;
    private AnimationDrawable thumbAnimation;
    private String[] moodResults;
    private Runnable mRunnable;
    private ImageView resultImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        thumbPrint = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbPrint);
        thumbPrint.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thumb_animation);
        thumbAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)thumbPrint.getBackground();

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        resultImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.resultImageView);

        thumbPrint.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                thumbAnimation.start();
                showImage();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    public void showImage() {
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            final int[] imageIds= {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three}; // This is your array with resource id of each image
            Random r = new Random();
            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int rand = (int)(Math.random()* moodResults.length);
                result.setText(moodResults[rand]);
                int randomInt = r.nextInt(imageIds.length);
                resultImageView.setBackgroundResource(imageIds[randomInt]); 
                
                //stop animation
                thumbAnimation.stop();
            }
        };

        //Here handler is called the first time; the code in mRunnable will execute after 5 seconds
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to override `OnBackPressed` method,

Comment: would this method work with it being the phones back button that is pressed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see It could work, when u hide the result view elements when not needed.
In other words: Try to reset all changes u made with `showImage();`
Im not at home to test, sry.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   if(resultImageView.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE){
      resultImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //or GONE 
      result.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }else{
      finish();
   }
}

@Override
public void run() {
   [...]
   resultImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   [...]
}
```

Comment: i have done the follwing, and it works howver the user wont be able to exit the app with back button @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

Comment: take care about the BackStack. Start the MainActivity many times will look right, but isn't the right way. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: what would be the right code to put in the onBackPressed method? it sends me from image view to main screen but then cannot exit app

Comment: to help I will need more information about the activity thats holds the ImageView. the structure you use

Comment: sure, i will edit the post and show the full activity as its only 1 activity

Comment: I am still having trouble with this, your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try this, this way u will avoid stacking the Activity up in BackStack.
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

Comment: is there a line of code i can add to this so that if pressed once more it will exit the app on the second press?